# Errors when opening an MSAccess table linked to Sharepoint

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint, dao

I have a Microsoft Access database containing a table that's actively linked to a List within Sharepoint. As soon as I make a change to a record in the table in Microsoft Access the change appears on the server.

I have some data that I want to add to that table. I want to perform some `INSERT` & `UPDATE` SQL queries to add that new data, because there's a lot of rows of it to add. The data I want to add is in a second table in this database, it is not linked to a sharepoint list.

The problem is, the second my SQL queries even touch my first table that's linked to Sharepoint I get the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Could not find installable ISAM.'

I've tried to do this with both `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao`, and `OleDb`. They both connect to the database just fine, but fail with the above error message whenever I attempt to touch the table linked to Sharepoint. They can edit any table not actively linked to Sharepoint just fine without any issues.

I spent a while googling the error I was getting, and found all sorts of different suggestions, but none of the suggestions I've seen have helped me on that. I'm certain that the link to Sharepoint is somehow causing this error, but if I get rid of the link my data won't be uploaded to Sharepoint like I want. So how do I get past this error and query the linked table?

The code I've tried to run for these

**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao**

```
    Dim dbEngine As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine
    Dim dbs As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database
    Dim rst As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Recordset2


   dbs = dbEngine.OpenDatabase(FileName)
   rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM SharepointLinkedTable") '<-- Crashes here
```

**OleDb**

```
    Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmdOLEDB As New OleDbCommand

    Dim strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & FileName
    cnnOLEDB.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
    cnnOLEDB.Open()
    cmdOLEDB.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SharepointLinkedTable"
    cmdOLEDB.Connection = cnnOLEDB

    Dim rdrOLEDB As OleDbDataReader = cmdOLEDB.ExecuteReader '<-- Crashes here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, including following some of the suggestions of `Cahaba Data` I figured out a way to get this to work.

First, while I can't find any documentation saying so, it seems based on my testing & research that Sharepoint 2016 doesn't allow running any SQL queries of any kind against a table actively linked to sharepoint. I found some threads elsewhere on the Internet of people who were able to do this in the past, but all of them were several years old, on earlier versions of Sharepoint.

So I unlinked my tables from Sharepoint & ran my SQL queries to move the data into the unlinked tables without issue. Lets call this table `Table1`.

With my data now moved into `Table1` I tried to restore the link between access and sharepoint to `Table1`, but there didn't seem to be an option to do this in Sharepoint. So instead I synced a second copy of my Sharepoint table to access, called `Table2`.

I tried to highlight all the rows in `Table1` and manually copy and paste the data into `Table2`, but I got some new messages that prevented me from inserting any data. The errors were quite vague, simply saying invalid data.

After some more research, I determined that certain columns in my tables were the issue. My Sharepoint table had a `Person or Groups` column, as well as a `Choice` column. The data I was trying to add to the table contained values that these two column types did not like. I ended up converting both those columns to `Single line of text` fields in Sharepoint, and recreating both `Table1` and `Table2` in Access.

After that I was able to copy and paste the data from `Table1` into `Table2`. The copy & pasting took some time (due to a large number of attachments in my records), but it worked & synced the data right to Sharepoint.

So bottom line, with some workarounds, yes you can still move data into Access Tables that are actively linked to Sharepoint, but it takes more work then it used to.

Answer (score 0):

As you define this as a Microsoft Access database I will presume that you have a standard Access file as the front end and that it is linking to SharePoint List as back end.

The topic is whether or not one can run "Action Queries" (Update, Append, Delete) on a linked SharePoint List table.  Offhand I'm not sure - so look that up first and see if there is an explicit negative.  Otherwise I would delete the link to the SharePoint List and remake it.  That's just basic "when all else failes - reboot..."

To help clarify the error cause: temporarily copy the SharePoint List into the front end so that it is a local table.  Note that you can't have 2 tables with the same name so the naming has to be managed.

Then set up your Update / Append queries - and be sure they run successfully to the local table test.  Save them as standard queries so they are in the navigation pane.  I suggest this as the error could be misleading and that the true cause is a bad query - rather than the link itself.

Then modify them to the linked table name and run them on the SharePoint List table and see.